# Apache couchdb 1.3.0 build from source not stopping

Tags: couchdb

I build apache couchdb 1.3.0 from source on ubuntu 11.10 by following the instructions on http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu

I was able to get the server up and running, however to get it to stop was not working.

I am using the commands below

```
sudo service couchdb start 

sudo service couchdb stop
```

Please let us know if there is something i am missing. The stop command stops the couch process but not the heart beat one and hence it restarts couch once again.

Comment: That's a little strange... what does `sudo kill -9 couchdb` do?

Comment: Well there was a change required in the stop script and my collegue has submitted a change request for the same. With that change we were able to get it working, the committers of couch have assured us that they will soon merge this to the source branch.

Comment: Cool, I was curious what killing it, then doing start and stop did. I think I've had problems with this too, but in development have killed it and the forked it. Thanks for the update, stop and start need to work for the production folks.